# Java 8 Composition, Currying shorthand

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

I have a stream of `BusinessObject`s, I need to set a value on each object, I want to use `Stream.map` but `map` takes a `Function<T,R>` and I have the target object, a discriminator value, and the new value. `setNewValueInBusinessObjectExample` shows what I want to do and `setNewValueInBusinessObjectWithFun` is what I need help with.

Agreed! I can just use `setNewValueInBusinessObjectExample` on the map but I want to see how the functional style looks like. Thanks

```
class BusinessObject {
    String firstField;
    String secondField;
}

class SomeDiscriminator {
    String value;
}

BusinessObject setNewValueInBusinessObjectExample(BusinessObject businessObject, 
     SomeDiscriminator discriminator, String newValue) {

    if(discriminator.value.equals("firstField")) {
        businessObject.firstField = newValue;
    } else {//secondField
        businessObject.secondField = newValue;
    }

    return businessObject;
}

Function<BusinessObject, Function<SomeDiscriminator, Function<String, BusinessObject>>> 
       setNewValueInBusinessObjectWithFun = {
    /* todo: using nested Function<T,R> */
}
```

Comment: When you say “I can just use setNewValueInBusinessObjectExample in the map”, show how you do it. Then, you already have the answer, as that is “functional style”.

Comment: thanks, stream.map(b -> setNewValueInBusinessObjectExample(b, "firstField", "newValueString")), i just want to see the shorthand for the setNewValueInBusinessObjectWithFun

Comment: `setNewValueInBusinessObjectWithFun = a -> b -> c -> setNewValueInBusinessObjectExample(a, b, c)` but what’s the advantage of the curried function? It’s not a short-hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in doubt with the construction and usage of functional interfaces, I recommend you to expand the whole thing to anonymous classes where the structure becomes obvious.

I also noticed the whole flow uses three parameters, the same your `setNewValueInBusinessObjectExample` does. Thus move the body of the method to the innermost anonymous class.

```
Function<BusinessObject, Function<SomeDiscriminator, Function<String, BusinessObject>>> setNewValueInBusinessObjectWithFun =
    new Function<BusinessObject, Function<SomeDiscriminator, Function<String, BusinessObject>>>() {
        @Override
        public Function<SomeDiscriminator, Function<String, BusinessObject>> apply(final BusinessObject businessObject) {
            return new Function<SomeDiscriminator, Function<String, BusinessObject>>() {
                @Override
                public Function<String, BusinessObject> apply(final SomeDiscriminator someDiscriminator) {
                    return new Function<String, BusinessObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public BusinessObject apply(final String newValue) {
                            if (someDiscriminator.value.equals("firstField")) {
                                businessObject.firstField = newValue;
                            } else {//secondField
                                businessObject.secondField = newValue;
                            }
                            return businessObject;
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

Now, pack the whole thing to lambda expressions and see what happens:

```
Function<BusinessObject, Function<SomeDiscriminator, Function<String, BusinessObject>>> setNewValueInBusinessObjectWithFun = 
    businessObject -> someDiscriminator -> newValue -> {
        if (someDiscriminator.value.equals("firstField")) {
            businessObject.firstField = newValue;
        } else {//secondField
            businessObject.secondField = newValue;
        }
        return businessObject;
    };
```

For sake of clarity, name the variables inside the lambdas expression correctly, otherwise you would not be able to work with them well. The usage is fairly simple (I moved setters to constructor for sake of brevity:

```
BusinessObject businessObject = new BusinessObject("oldValue");
setNewValueInBusinessObjectWithFun
    .apply(businessObject)                                  // apply to an object
    .apply(new SomeDiscriminator("firstField"))             // finds its field
    .apply("newValue");                                     // sets a new value
```

---

However, I recommend you to define a custom `@FunctionalInterface` with more straightforward definition...

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyFunction<T, R, U> {
    T apply(T t, R r, U u);
}
```

... and usage ...

```
MyFunction<BusinessObject, SomeDiscriminator, String> myFunction = 
    (businessObject, someDiscriminator, newValue) -> {
        if (someDiscriminator.value.equals("firstField")) {
            businessObject.firstField = newValue;
        } else {
            businessObject.secondField = newValue;
        }
        return businessObject;
    };

BusinessObject businessObject = new BusinessObject("oldValue");
myFunction.apply(businessObject, new SomeDiscriminator("firstField"), "newValue");
```

Comment: and is this the best way to pass in the map call: stream.map(businessObject -> setNewValueInBusinessObjectWithFun.apply(businessObject).apply("firstField").apply("newValue"))?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I get what you might need, but something like this?

```
static Function<BusinessObject, Function<SomeDiscriminator, Function<String, BusinessObject>>>
    setNewValueInBusinessObjectWithFun =
    x -> y -> z -> {
        if ("firstfield".equals(y.value)) {
            x.firstField = z;
        } else {
            x.secondField = z;
        }
        return x;
    };
```

And usage would be:

```
    BusinessObject bo = new BusinessObject();
    bo.firstField = "test";

    SomeDiscriminator sd = new SomeDiscriminator();
    sd.value = "firstField";
    bo = setNewValueInBusinessObjectWithFun.apply(bo).apply(sd).apply("value");

    System.out.println(bo.firstField);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need to be complex. If you have a `Stream<BusinessObject>`, then neither `SomeDiscriminator` nor the `String` value is a stream element.

So it's a `Function<BusinessObject, BusinessObject>` that you need to pass to `map`:

```
Stream<BusinessObject> businessObjectStream = null;
SomeDiscriminator discriminator = null; String newValue = "";

Function<BusinessObject, BusinessObject> mapper = businessObject -> {
    if (discriminator.value.equals("firstField")) {
        businessObject.firstField = newValue;
    } else {//secondField
        businessObject.secondField = newValue;
    }

    return businessObject;
};
```

Called with:

```
businessObjectStream.map(mapper);
```

Even if the `discriminator.value.equals("firstField")` logic were dependent on dynamic values in the stream object, you would have needed perhaps a `Predicate<...>` somewhere, but really not even a higher-order function that returns a function dynamically.